# How to set host-header depending on choosen backend when using HAProxy as loadbalancer

Tags: haproxy

Under certain circumstances it is required to modify the host-header based on the backend selected by HAProxy loadbalancing (an example is described here: https://www.claudiokuenzler.com/blog/919/haproxy-how-use-different-http-host-header-for-each-backend-server)

My internet research shows that there are basically two ways to achieve this:

a) use "http-send-name-header Host" (not recommended according the HAProxy docs: https://www.haproxy.com/documentation/hapee/latest/onepage/#4.2-http-send-name-header)

b) use " http-request set-header Host ... if { srv_id 1 }"

(the following article describes these two techniques: https://serverfault.com/questions/876871/configure-haproxy-to-include-host-headers-for-different-backends)

Option a) works as expected but it is discouraged to be use (see https://www.haproxy.com/documentation/hapee/latest/onepage/#4.2-http-send-name-header).

For this reason I am trying to option b). Unfortunately the config cowardly refuses to work:

```
backend loadbalanced-backends

        mode http

        balance roundrobin

        option forwardfor

        http-request set-header Host one.domain.com if { srv_id 1 }

        http-request set-header Host two.domain.com if { srv_id 2 }

        server one one.domain.com:8000

        server two two.domain.com:8000
```

The warnings printed in the log:

```
[WARNING]  (1) : config : parsing ....cfg:14] : anonymous acl will never match because it uses keyword 'srv_id' which is incompatible with 'backend http-request header rule'

[WARNING]  (1) : config : parsing ....cfg:15] : anonymous acl will never match because it uses keyword 'srv_id' which is incompatible with 'backend http-request header rule'
```

Besids the warning the logged request-header show that the host is not changed to one.domain.com resp. two.domain.com.

What exactly means the warning "anonymous acl will never match..."? I do not see what is wrong with the configuration. Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: Solution a) as [stated in the comments](https://serverfault.com/questions/876871/configure-haproxy-to-include-host-headers-for-different-backends#comment1191260_876880) of the linked answer does not work. According to [this thread](https://discourse.haproxy.org/t/http-response-set-header-with-condition-not-working/3108), the decision you are trying to make cannot be made in the `backend` section but has to be done in the `frontend` section, when the request is incoming.

Comment: In the first blog post you reference, the solution works because it uses hardcoded, static values for each backend. It does not look at anything from the request and does not do decisions.